# Change of variable in double and triple integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration

I learn double and triples integral as same as change of variable and then surface integral in my class so there is some conflict between how to do double integrals

Here is how the text book say about change in variable

[image]

so it can be said that this is like integral over parametric surface. Then for integral over parametric surface

[image]

I don't understand why they are different. Both of them are all integral a parametric region (surface) why the latter don't need to use Jacobian while changing variables.

Comment: How do you understand the term $|\mathbf{r}_u\times\mathbf{r}_v|$?

Comment: It is the absolute value of the cross product between partial derivative of $u$ and $v$ of $r(u,v)$ which is the parametric equation of the surface

Comment: So, isn't that similar to Jacobian?